# iOS Push to another view controller get stuck

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an base view controller and all my viewcontrollers inherit it.

```
@interface BaseViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.backButton];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}

- (void) popToPreViewController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - getter and setter

- (UIButton *) backButton {
    if (!_backButton) {
        _backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        [_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popToPreViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _backButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    return _backButton;
}

@end
```

Sometimes push to another view controller will get stuck ,but the app does not crash.Press home button and open the app again, it shows the another view controller . Is there something wrong with this baseviewcontroller ?

Comment: provide more code, that how you are presenting child view controllers from base view controller

Comment: One issues which I can see is very small frame rect set for back button '_backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];'. It should be at least 45x45 to receive proper user tap evert. Use button inset to place button image and keep frame 45x45 or bigger

Comment: Did it solved your issue as well ?

Comment: @aman.sood No, I'm in a puzzle about this.

Comment: @lionserdar nope...

Answer (score 0):

I have been troubled by this problem for a long time, now find a solution.
The reason for this problem is that the root controller performs a gesture pop operation, the problem described above occurs. The workaround is to disable the gesture pop at the root controller and open the gesture pop on the non root controller.

```
/// The controller is fully displayed, opening the gesture pop
 Func navigationController (_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

     If viewControllers.first == viewController {
         InteractivePopGestureRecognizer? .isEnabled = false
     } Else {
         InteractivePopGestureRecognizer? .isEnabled = true
     }

     NavigationBar.sendSubview (toBack: navigationBar.overlay)
 }
```